# Debiting and crediting (changing) state data in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: transactions, state, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

All examples for Hyperledger Fabric seem to focus on posting a new state that just overwrite the previous state of a record, for example owner A is replaced by owner B for car 1.

I haven't found any example of "stateful" change of state though. For example when we have a bank account record in the state, with a balance. We would post a debit or credit transaction to the ledger that would need to read the current balance of the account, and decrease or increase it. This would possibly involve putting a lock on the account state record until the change is completed. Are there any examples of this, how can this be done properly in chaincode to ensure data consistency?

Comment: Balance transfer sample shows a way of how to do this https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer. And as to the lock that you mentioned, Hyperledger Fabric is designed in this way that there's no double-spending. The execute-order-validate architecture for transactions, having chaincode for state management deals with the problem mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric has an example of bank-transfer-like [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/high-throughput) - high throughput

Because of the Read-Write set, we can not make a chaincode which modify the same key multiple times at the same time ([MVCC_READ_CONFLICT] error). You can read more about RW set [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/readwrite.html), or [this article](https://medium.com/@spsingh559/understanding-the-read-write-set-in-hyperledger-fabric-92109d2a87ed)

The key idea of this sample is that it makes a unique key with the same prefix for every transaction: varName~op~value~txID, where a transaction params include:

- varName: account
- op: + or - operator
- value: transaction value
- txID: this will make the key unique

After that, at the GET query phase, it uses `GetStateByPartialCompositeKey()` function to get theses records which include the account in the key and then sum up to get the current balance of that account

Hope this can give you some ideas!

Comment: Still, in this example, to avoid overspending of the current balance, we need to check if we have enough money in the account, before withdrawal transaction is allowed and recorded in the ledger, so we sill need to do "locking" of the current balance - how can this be done correctly?

Comment: I think you need a third-party service to handle that case. There're 2 ways in my mind: (1) using an auto-increment nonce number, instead of txID for the unique key. In this case, we can calculate the current balance before submitting the transaction. (2) Manage the value of each account as the world state, combined with the nonce to ensure the accuracy of the data. The banking problem is quite difficult, so I think a  system which can keep-it-safe will be much more complicated